# Does OpenGL have a function that loads texture from a resource?

Tags: opengl, textures, loadimage

Does OpenGL have a simple function that loads texture from a resource file, so I could get rid of `(HBITMAP)LoadImage();` function that I use instead.

As an example in DirectX it can be done by `D3DXCreateTextureFromResourceA();` function.

Comment: OpenGL has nothing to do with asset loading. It only knows to draw pixels. That's it.You must use external libs to load your assets into memory.

Comment: @MichaelIV: That being said it's perfectly possible to implement asset from resource loading. In fact in my earliest OpenGL programs I actually did this (the code is horrible though).

Comment: @datenwolf of course!,but many people new to OpenGL mistakenly assume the API provides assets loading features.

Answer (score 0):

Use Qt, you will find it's easy to write code with OpenGL.

You can load a lot of image with different formats.

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "open image file", ".", "Image files (*.bmp *.jpg *.pbm *.pgm *.png *.ppm *.xbm *.xpm);;All files (*.*)");
QImage image;

image.load(fileName);
```

Also, it is easy to change normal image to OpenGL texture.

```
QImage textureImage = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(image);
GLuint glTexture;

glGenTextures(1, &glTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB16, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureImage.bits());
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```